# Agent.ToolsDirectory is not set error while running yarn task in TFS server 2015. How can I fix it?

Tags: tfs

is there any default Agent.ToolsDirectory path.
I tried to find the Agent.ToolsDirectory path in agent but that was not set.
Please provide your suggestions to resolve this issue, Thank in advance.

Comment: Do you get this error when you run other tasks? Could you share the entire log? Please try to re-configure your build agent or configure a new build agent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v1-windows) to see whether you would reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

"Agent.ToolsDirectory" variable was added from build agent version: 2.115.0 which is available after TFS2017 Update 1.

TFS2015 use the legacy 1.x agent which does not support this variable. Refer to this link for details: [Variables](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/minagent.md#variables).